# Horizontal Subnavigation Menu with Angular 2+ Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a **horizontal** subnavigation menu like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp) using [Angular Material](https://v5.material.angular.io/).

The HTML and CSS on the website is straightforward enough, but is there a "best practice" way to do this using the Angular Material framework?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a horizontal sub-navigation is recommended by Material Design - [the standard doesn't recommend sub-navigations](https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#types-of-navigation), but recommend (borrowing from the same link above):

> Forward navigation can be implemented using:
>
> - Content containers such as cards, lists, or image lists
> - Buttons that advance to another screen
> - In-app search on one or more screens
> - Links within content

for the components to implement the 4 bullet points above, kindly check [this link](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/)